# Undefined variable in foreach loop

Tags: php

When I do a `foreach()` loop, the current array element's value `$recipient` is not defined on the line `->to($recipient)`. Why is this?

**PHP Code (throws error)**

```
foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    Mail::send('emails.invite', $data, function($m){
        $m
            ->from('welcome@website.com', Auth::user()->name)
            ->to($recipient)
            ->subject('Auth::user()->name has invited you!');
    });
}
```

**Error**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: recipient
```

**PHP Code (NO error)**

```
foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    echo $recipient;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `use` keyword. Change the code  to :

```
foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    Mail::send('emails.shareListing', $data, function($m) use($recipient) {
        $m
            ->from('share@asd.com', Auth::user()->name)
            ->to($recipient)
            ->subject('Auth::user()->name has shared a listing with you!');
    });
}
```

See [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php) - especially the third example. Quote:

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be declared in the function header.

Comment: You are welcome! Had the problem once to. The PHP documentation is saying not much about this.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're inside the scope of the function.

Assuming you're using the PEAR package here, I don't understand why you're passing a function at all: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

If you meant to be doing this, you can use the `use` keyword to pass the variable into the function scope:

```
function($m) use($recipient) {
```